# Prevent completion of files for 'make' command in zsh shell

Tags: zsh, make, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

### Context

- `zsh` shell,
- `oh-my-zsh` framework,
- no special `zsh`'s configuration (same problem with or without `zsh-completions`): see `.zshrc` at the end.

### Trouble

If a directory contains:

- a `makefile` with targets: `hello`, `hello.o` and `main.o`,
- say, 3 files `foo`, `bar` and `baz`,

invoking `make` + ↹ displays as completion:

> `bar       baz       foo       hello     hello.o   main.o    makefile`

instead of only the `makefile`' s targets.

### Question

How can I customize `zsh` in order it behaves as `bash` (which displays only the `makefile`' s targets) in this respect?

### Configuration file

Here is my `.zshrc`:

```
export ZSH=/home/bitouze/.oh-my-zsh

ZSH_THEME="gnzh"

plugins=(git zsh-completions)
autoload -U compinit && compinit

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

export LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8

source $HOME/.aliases

# texdoc completion
compctl -k "(($(grep ^name $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFROOT)/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb | grep -v '\.' | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ' ')))" texdoc

export ANDROID_HOME="/home/bitouze/Android/Sdk"
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre


#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR SDKMAN TO WORK!!!
export SDKMAN_DIR="/home/bitouze/.sdkman"
[[ -s "/home/bitouze/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "/home/bitouze/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can ask `zsh` to only display `targets` *tag* for the `make` command completion with

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:make:*' tag-order 'targets'
```

Add above code somewhere after the line

```
autoload -U compinit && compinit
```

Comment: Works nicely! Strange this `zstyle` is not the default.

Comment: How does it work in the background. How does ZSH know make targets?

Comment: @Krishna It looks for the Makefile and parses it.